# C# WPF: Use RadioButton IsChecked property for DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my application, the text in a specific `TextBlock` depends on which of the two `RadioButton` is checked. Below is an example of the xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="UTScanForm.Support.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UTScanForm.Support"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <RadioButton x:Name="RB1" Content="RB1"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="RB2" Content="RB2"/>
            <TextBlock Text="none">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=RB1}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="RB1"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=RB2}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="RB2"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As the above code indicates, there are two radio buttons, `RB1` and `RB2`. If `RB1` is checked, the text in the textblock should become `RB1`, and `RB2` otherwise. However, the code is not working. Can you please point out what mistake(s) I've made and what would a correct solution be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to [dependency property value precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence). The `Text="none"` attribute on the TextBlock overrides anything the style does. This is a feature, not a bug: It lets you set defaults with a style used on multiple controls, and then override them for specific instances.

The fix is easy: Set the default "none" text with a style setter, and the other style setters can override that.

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="none" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=RB1}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="RB1"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=RB2}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="RB2"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

This does not apply to DataTemplate or ControlTemplate triggers, by the way. They can override attributes.